# gst-inspect-1.0: undefined symbol: gst_tracer_factory_get_type

Tags: raspberry-pi, element, gstreamer

Gstreamer custom plugin can not be loaded, reporting no element. gst-inspect-1.0 shows error for the following command:

`$ gst-inspect-1.0 /usr/local/lib/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmyplugin.so`

> gst-inspect-1.0: symbol lookup error: gst-inspect-1.0: undefined symbol: gst_tracer_factory_get_type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have found the issue. Two different library search path was causing the issue. If Gstreamer is installed from source then the library path is /usr/local/lib/ and if installed from packages then the path is /usr/lib/arm...../.